# C# excel formatar coluna

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, number-format

Estou tentando formatar uma coluna do excel para o formato de moeda.

`excelWorksheet.Range["S1", "S" + linhas].NumberFormat = "R$ #.###,00"`

Porém isso faz com que formate deste modo "RR$ 3500,00".

Na celula está 3500 e eu gostaria que ficasse: R$ 3.500,00 que fazendo na mão seria alterando o dado para moeda e o símbolo para R$.

Obrigado.

Comment: Está usando Epplus?

Comment: Não. Apenas visual studio e o excel.

Comment: Com excel você quer dizer o Interop?

Comment: Isso! Worksheet, workbook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só colocar o $, pois ele pega o idioma do arquivo para gerar o simbolo da moeda.

```
excelWorksheet.Range["S1", "S" + linhas].NumberFormat = "$ #.###,00"
```

Comment: Adicionando, deixei assim: "$ #.###0,00", pois quando era 0 ele estava formatando assim: ,00.