# Problema com exportação para Excel usando C#

Tags: c#

Estou exportando uma lista para o excel, ocorre que em um dos campos, "conteúdo do número de nota fiscal" e muito grande, o excel tenta formatar o mesmo, gerando caracteres especiais.

Existe alguma forma de selecionar o campo da nota e formatar ele?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo assim:

```
      var data = new[]{ 
                           new{ Name="OS", Email="ram@techbrij.com", ChaveNF="8715421643464674616464646476464646464646761322031313787" },
                           new{ Name="Shyam", Email="shyam@techbrij.com", ChaveNF="8715421643464674616464646476464646464646761455322031313322031313" },
                           new{ Name="Mohan", Email="mohan@techbrij.com", ChaveNF="8715421643464674616464646476464646464646761322031313" },
                           new{ Name="Sohan", Email="sohan@techbrij.com", ChaveNF="8715421643464674616464646476464646464646761322031313" },
                           new{ Name="Karan", Email="karan@techbrij.com", ChaveNF="8715421643464674616464646476464646464646761322031313" },
                           new{ Name="Brij", Email="brij@techbrij.com", ChaveNF="8715421643464674616464646476464646464646761322031313" }                       
     };





 private static void CovertToExcel<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        using (TextWriter output = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\Public\RelDCL.xls"))
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                output.Write(prop.DisplayName); // header
                output.Write("\t");
            }
            output.WriteLine();
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
                {


                    output.Write(prop.Converter.ConvertToString(prop.GetValue(item)));
                    output.Write("\t");
                }
                output.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mostre um exemplo

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, veja uma lista de exemplo com um campo valor ChaveNF

Comment: ok, `ChaveNF` é do tipo `string` correto? de que caracteres especiais você está falando que aparecem no excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itasouza, por favor veja o exemplo:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bankAccounts = new List<Account> {
                new Account { ID = 345678, Balance = 541.27},
                new Account {ID = 1230221,Balance = -1237.44},
                new Account {ID = 346777,Balance = 3532574},
                new Account {ID = 235788,Balance = 1500.033333}};
            DisplayInExcel(bankAccounts);
        }
        static void DisplayInExcel(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
        {
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
            workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "ID Number";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Current Balance";
            var row = 1;
            foreach (var acct in accounts)
            {
                row++;
                workSheet.Cells[row, "A"] = acct.ID;
                workSheet.Cells[row, "B"] = acct.Balance;

            }
            workSheet.Range["B2", "B" + row].NumberFormat = "#,###.00 €";
            workSheet.Columns[1].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[2].AutoFit();
        }
    }
    public class Account
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
oSheet.get_Range("B", "B").NumberFormat = "000.000.000/0000-00";
excelWorksheet.Range["S1", "S" + linhas].NumberFormat = "R$ #.###,00"
```

Veja mais em:

[Formatting Excel cells (currency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338156/formatting-excel-cells-currency)

[Formatar colunas de um arquivo Excel gerado pelo C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/be4ed089-7d78-40b0-9b6b-711939a67007/formatar-colunas-de-um-arquivo-excel-gerado-pelo-c?forum=vscsharppt)

[C# excel formatar coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220975/c-excel-formatar-coluna)

Comment: Agradeço, vou testar

Comment: @itasouza, por favor teste. Se funcionar me pontue pq aqui é difícil demais de conseguir pontos! KKKKK!

Comment: @FabioIn, concordo sobre ser difícil pontuar, mas verificando o quanto você mesmo votou esse mês, é menos de um voto por dia :( .... mas sou super a favor de votar em todas perguntas e respostas que tenham qualidade, façam sentido e que tenham exigido esforço de  alguém que contribuí aqui no SOpt! :)

Comment: @George Wurthmann , você tem razão...

Comment: @FabioIn, agradeço a a resposta, eu já pontuei, eu sei como e difícil

Comment: @itasouza, obrigado.